# Choices for Securing Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Ranger is used for security with Hortonworks. What are the choices if someone is not using Hortonworks or Cloudera, and just using apache distribution of Hadoop?

Comment: Ranger is an Apache project: http://ranger.apache.org/

Comment: Managing your cluster with Apache Ambari is a good way to do it, it allows you to install Ranger and to manage your cluster with a GUI: http://ambari.apache.org/

Comment: We are planning to use amazon EMR. Is there anything comparable like Ranger in AWS EMR? Can you use Ambari with EMR?